# wcf on IIS for use in android

Tags: android, json, wcf, iis

I'm trying to achieve a wcf service hosted in IIS, as a link in an adroid app using an online database. For now I'm just following tutorials to get the techniques working. I'm stuck on getting the wcf service to work properly in IIS.

I followed this example to create the wcf: 
    http://www.wcftutorial.net/How_to_create_RESTful_Service.aspx

On my local PC it works fine, using the console application to host the wcf service. When requesting the below url in my browser it shows me data in json format as expected. This is also what I need in the next step.

```
http://localhost:8090/MyFirstRESTfulService/EmployeeService/Employee
```

**Hosting in IIS**

Now I want to host this wcf in IIS. I follow this lead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (I've seen several others and experimented with them as well, but it all comes down to the same thing)

The physical address for the service is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyFirstRESTfulService.
The actual code for the wcf has been melted in one file (service.cs) and saved in a subfolder App_Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace MyFirstRESTfulService
{
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    [DataMember ]
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Designation { get; set; }
}


public partial class EmployeeData
{
    private static readonly EmployeeData _instance = new EmployeeData();

    private EmployeeData() { }

    public static EmployeeData Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }


    private List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee() { EmpId  = 1, Fname = "Sam", Lname = "kumar", JoinDate=new DateTime(2010,7, 21), Age=30,Salary=10000,Designation="Software Engineer"},
        new Employee() { EmpId = 2, Fname = "Ram", Lname = "kumar", JoinDate=new DateTime(2009,6,8), Age=35,Salary=10000,Designation="Senior Software Engineer"},    
        new Employee() { EmpId = 3, Fname = "Sasi", Lname = "M", JoinDate=new DateTime(2008,3,5), Age=39,Salary=10000,Designation="Projet Manager"},  
        new Employee() { EmpId = 4, Fname = "Praveen", Lname = "KR", JoinDate=new DateTime(2010, 5,1), Age=56,Salary=10000,Designation="Projet Manager"},
        new Employee() { EmpId = 5, Fname = "Sathish", Lname = "V", JoinDate = new DateTime(2006,12,15), Age=72,Salary=10000,Designation="Senior Software Engineer"},  
        new Employee() { EmpId = 6, Fname = "Rosh", Lname = "A", JoinDate=new DateTime(2009,2,2), Age=25,Salary=10000,Designation="Software Engineer"}
    };

    public List<Employee> EmployeeList
    {
        get
        {
            return empList;
        }
    }


    public void Update(Employee updEmployee)
    {
        Employee existing = empList.Find(p => p.EmpId == updEmployee.EmpId);

        if (existing == null)
            throw new KeyNotFoundException("Specified Employee cannot be found");

        existing.Fname = updEmployee.Fname;
        existing.Lname = updEmployee.Lname;
        existing.Age = updEmployee.Age;
    }

    public void Delete(int empid)
    {
        Employee existing = empList.Find(p => p.EmpId == empid);
        empList.Remove(existing);
    }
    public void Add(Employee newEmployee)
    {
        empList.Add(new Employee
        {
            EmpId = newEmployee.EmpId,
            Fname = newEmployee.Fname,
            Lname = newEmployee.Lname,
            Age = newEmployee.Age,
            JoinDate = DateTime.Now,
            Designation = newEmployee.Designation,
            Salary = newEmployee.Salary
        });
    }
}












[ServiceContract()]
public interface IEmployeeService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Employee", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json )]
    [OperationContract]
    List<Employee> GetAllEmployeeDetails();

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetEmployee?id={id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    Employee GetEmployee(int Id);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "EmployeePOST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    void AddEmployee(Employee newEmp);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "EmployeePUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateEmployee(Employee newEmp);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "Employee/{empId}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteEmployee(string empId);
}












[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed )]
public  class EmployeeService: IEmployeeService 
{

   public List <Employee> GetAllEmployeeDetails()
    {
        return EmployeeData.Instance.EmployeeList;
    }

    public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> empList = EmployeeData.Instance.EmployeeList.Where(x => x.EmpId == id);

        if (empList != null)
            return empList.First<Employee>();
        else
            return null;
    }


   public void AddEmployee(Employee newEmp)
   {
       EmployeeData.Instance.Add(newEmp);
   }


    public void UpdateEmployee( Employee newEmp)
    {
        EmployeeData.Instance.Update(newEmp);
    }


     public void DeleteEmployee(string empId)
    {
        EmployeeData.Instance.Delete(System.Convert .ToInt32 (empId));
    }
}

}
```

In the root folder for the wcf service I've created 2 more files.

Service.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyFirstRESTfulService.EmployeeService" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/service.cs" %>
```

and web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyFirstRESTfulService.EmployeeService">      
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyFirstRESTfulService.IEmployeeService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/SelfHostedServiceConsole" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>



        </service>
    </services>


    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">

                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
                set the value below to false and remove the 
                metadata endpoint above before deployment -->

                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for 
                debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  
                Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->

                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

On the webserver when I call this url

```
http://localhost/MyFirstRESTfulService/service.svc
```

in the browser, I get a page saying "You have created a service. To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service." and so on.

Just like this link

```
http://localhost:8090/MyFirstRESTfulService/EmployeeService/Employee
```

returned the json formatted data when using the console application, I'm expecting the same now when using

```
http://localhost/MyFirstRESTfulService/EmployeeService/Employee
```

or maybe

```
http://localhost/MyFirstRESTfulService/service.svc/EmployeeService/Employee
```

But I can't get this working. I get 'page not found' kind of errors with these links.

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for the long post, and thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an endpointbehavior to your endpoint to enable the restfulness. And I also think you need to use webHttpBinding instead of basicHttpBinding.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyFirstRESTfulService.IEmployeeService" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttp">
```

......

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebHttp">
        <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

When you self hosted the WCF i guess you used WebServiceHost? This gives you the correct configuration for restful-behavior.

Comment: You are right, thank you. Meanwhile I found another good link: http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/05/wcf-rest-service-with-xml-json-response-format-according-to-content-type-header/ confirming your answer.